# Call a ClickOnce application from a Scheduled Task

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, scheduled-tasks, clickonce

I'm developing a WinForms app compiled as ClickOnce that is updated almost every week. When doing a compile/publish using Visual Studio it creates a setup program like this.

[image]

We upload the new versions to an SFTP and the installed app detect updates on launch and install it automaticaly, and that's ok since the Desktop and Start Menu shortcuts always launch the app, check updates, install it, etc etc

The problem comes when I try to find the instalation path. When I follow the shortcut path, every update change the path and create a **new** installation in %AppData% in a **new** folder like this

```
"C:\Users\xxx.xxx\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\2A8M779Z.JPR\8K5C4HPP.9ZG\xxx..xxx_0000000000000000_0003.0007_fe63fb4bbf811e24\xxx.exe"
```

[image]

I want to launch my app with a timer (i.e. every day at 0:00) by using the Windows Task Scheduler, but since the path changes when updated I need:

1.1.) To program the launch of the app for (possible) updates and get the new installation path.

1.2.) Programaticaly editing existing Task Scheduler tasks and change the program path to the new installation path

Another option that could work for me (and is cumulative with before options) is

2.) Get a compilation from Visual Studio that generates a setup that always install the app in the same path, i.e. C:/myapp/ overwriting older versions

Before talking about code I need to think what's the more viable/scalable option (if it is even possible) and why, so please comment and I will have this post updated.

*About Windows Task Scheduler: I mean this is the way I **manually** create tasks right now. But manually updating the app and changing the tasks program path every week would be really tedious...*

[image]

Comment: Sorry I'm Spanish, you are right, in English it is called Task Scheduler, I edit the post. And yes, it is a ClickOnce application, and the problem is I can't launch it from the Task **Scheduler** because it changes the installation path on every update

Comment: I assume you need to reference/target the ClickOnce "*.application" file on your share to get the app started.

Comment: That automatically updates the app so the Task Scheduler things feels useless to me if its just for updating. Don't your user start the app via the Application file?

Comment: This isn't about English vs Spanish. It's how the Windows features are called. If you search for the correct terms, eg `clickonce application scheduled task`  you'll find several SO answers. You can start the application using the path to the `.application` file, eg `start path\to\myapp.application`. What many answers omit is that `start` uses the Windows Shell to start applications, which means the user must be logged on. If you want to *upgrade* though, many answers suggest calling the `appref-ms` file.

Comment: Is the real question how to automatically upgrade the ClickOnce application perhaps?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236754/c-sharp-process-start-a-clickonce-application-what-url

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes, the real question is how to automatically upgrade the ClickOnce application, but also how to reference it from Task Scheduler since its path changes on every update, I'm going to try with start command as you said, thanks a lot dude